# How can I catch dismiss a Modal in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I used modal to set up and use the code below in React Native.

```
<Modal
      animationType="slide"
      presentationStyle="pageSheet"            // here!!!
      visible={this.state.modalVisible}
>
    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
         <Text>Hello World!</Text>
         <Button
             title="Close"
             onPress={() => {
               this._setModalVisible(false);
             }}
          />
    </View>
</Modal>
```

in iOS, the page comes up in a popup form at the front and closes when you drag it down. I can control `this.state.modalVisible` via a button, but the dragging modal doesn't catch.

I want to change `this.state.modalVisible` by catching the event when it closes. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26892) with the React Native Modal component.

As an alternative, you could try the [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) library which supports the behaviour you are after.